# Running drush up to several sites folders at once

Tags: drush, updating

In my server's root folder I have the folder `www` that contains sites of all my websites. All of these are Drupal.

Navigating into each folder and doing `drush --no-backup up -y` each time, can be both time consuming and tiring.

Is there a way to update all sites at once, with drush, instead of installing third-party software (like Ansible, IINW).

The command `drush --no-backup up -y @sites` won't help in this case, as it is aimed for multisites, and I don't work with multisites at all.

Update 1 - Note (might not be relevant when you read this question):

```
<?php
$aliases['mine'] = array(
'site-list' => array('@site1', '@site2')
);
```

The file containing it should be putted under public_html (or www) with permissions as 755 or 644.

Answer (score 5):

First off, look to the trivial solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
drush @site1 up -y --no-backup
drush @site2 up -y --no-backup
```

You don't need to install Ansible to start automating; simple bash scripts can be used to combine repetitive tasks very easily.  If you are on Windows, you can install [Git for Windows](https://git-for-windows.github.io/), which includes a Bash shell, or, if you really don't want to install anything at all, use a .bat file.

There is also a Drush solution:  Drush can run the same command on multiple sites if you give it a list of aliases:

```
drush @site1,@site2 up -y --no-backup
```

If you have a lot of sites, you can make a site alias that is a list of site aliases:

```
<?php
$aliases['mine'] = array(
  'site-list' => array('@site1', '@site2')
);
```

Then:

```
drush @mine up -y --no-backup
```

Comment: About the direct drush solution - Just to try, in CentOS terminal I Went to www folder and did: drush @site1,@site2,@site3,@site4,@site5 --no-backup up -y but then I got "Warning: not found".

Comment: Oh okay I get it, I need to give the folder names...

Comment: Well, still "Not found" even when I did in www: drush @first.co.il,@second.co.uk,@third.com --no-backup up -y but then I got "Warning: not found"

Comment: You need to define site aliases for all of your sites. See https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/master/examples/example.aliases.drushrc.php